# Avatar Item Layering issues

Tags: php, css, image, z-index

I'm having an issue with trying to make for instance hair fit under a hat without the hair going through the hat because the hair image is taller than the hat ect.

[image: avatar image example]

as you can see my (quick hair) is displaying through the hat which is my issue and i don't really know how to fix it. The images load from a mysql database and are layered currently.

Comment: Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?  (I have a question... what in the plastic does mysql have to do with this?)

Comment: You can not do that using pure PNG. SVG masking and clipping tricks  may help: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: @spencer7593 i don't know why i added the last bit maybe to inform if someone where to ask >.> And yes there was a question asking how i can get the hair layer to clip or render under the hat layer that way it doesn't show over the hair...